# Is it possible to compile C code to Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, c, code-translation

I've found a programming tool called emscripten that can compile c++ code to Javascript code using LLVM. Is it possible to compile C to Javascript using Emscripten (or a similar tool?)

Comment: Just because I am curious, what situation comes up that this is a solution that is needed?

Comment: emscripten works with C as well

Comment: @thatidiotguy See Atwoods Law ("any application that can be written in JavaScript will eventually be written in JavaScript").

Comment: http://cluecc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @thatidiotguy In some cases, it would be useful to port a C library to Javascript, and emscripten might make it easier to do that.

Comment: Now go translate this to JavaScript: `__asm__("add %esp, 0x8\n xor %eax, %eax\n ret")`

Comment: @H2CO3 http://bellard.org/jslinux/index.html

Comment: @melpomene been there, done that.

Comment: @melpomene Yeah, though that isn't a compiler, it's an x86 emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Emscripten doesn't know a thing about C++. It operates on LLVM IR, and cares relatively little how that code was created. You can compile just about anything (that has a LLVM-IR-emitting compiler), including C++, to LLVM IR and pass that to Emscripten.

Note that the result is highly unlikely to resemble human-written JavaScript, and will be unfit for maintenance and further development. It also has some inherent [restrictions](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/CodeGuidlinesAndLimitations) -- JavaScript isn't machine code, and even if it was, it wouldn't necessarily be compatible to the assumptions of some low-level code.